# unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'int' XOR Decryption

Tags: python

I am trying to decrypt single byte XOR as follows (executable as-is):

```
from binascii import unhexlify

if __name__ == "__main__":

    encoded = unhexlify("7f454c467f454c467f454c46")
    for key in range(256):
        decoded = ''.join(chr(b ^ key) for b in encoded)
        if decoded.isprintable():
            print(key, decoded)
```

I get the following error on execution:

```
File "temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    decoded = ''.join(chr(b ^ key) for b in encoded)
File "temp.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    decoded = ''.join(chr(b ^ key) for b in encoded)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'int'
```

What gives? Thanks!

Comment: What is unclear? You cannot apply ^ to a string.

Comment: `b` is a string, not a number.

Comment: int(b) breaks the code, how to fix it?

Comment: Of course `int(b)` will break - have you looked at what `encoded` looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ord` to convert your character into an integer before doing your XOR.

```
decoded = ''.join(chr(ord(b) ^ key) for b in encoded)
```

Comment: gives `syntax error: can't assign to function call
`

Comment: What did you write?

Comment: `decoded = ''.join(chr(b ^ key) for ord(b) in encoded)`

Comment: `decoded = ''.join(chr(ord(b) ^ key) for b in encoded)`

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that `b` is string and `key` is integer.

if you want to use `^` you need both variables to be integer - you can use `ord(b)` and it will solve you problem.

`decoded = ''.join(chr(ord(b) ^ key) for b in encoded)`

Comment: Nope, does not work, gives `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`